# ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on the binding 'WebHttpBinding' ('Anonymous')

Tags: wcf

I follow this (https://bishwaranjan.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/how-to-upload-files-using-kendo-file-upload-and-wcf-service/) article step by step, but I have the following  exption:

> The authentication schemes configured on the host ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on the binding 'WebHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the  element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on my dev box this afternoon using Visual Studio 2013 community edition.

My solution was to single click the project name, then change Properties > Development Server > Anonymous Authentication to "Enabled".

Here is a copy of my web.config file as well:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RiddenGear.AJAX.GuestServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="RiddenGear.AJAX.GuestServices">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RiddenGear.AJAX.GuestServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RiddenGear.AJAX.GuestServices"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

As a side bar, please note that this is my dev config.  We do run another config for live that forces connections over https.  Once you get things rolling in dev you'll likely want to upgrade your config to handle these connections as well.